# SVN and WebSVN with different users access restriction on multiple repositories on linux

Tags: linux, svn

and first of all sorry for my english. I've installed an ubuntu server 10.04.1 with apache2, subversion, svn_dav and websvn. (and others services of course, like php5, mysql 5.1, etc). I've configured my svn with multiple repositories, and each one with differents groups and users, like:

```
/var/myrepos/repo1 group: mygroup1
/var/myrepos/repo2 group: mygroup2
/var/myrepos/repo3 user: johndoe
```

With an easy access on svn_dav, works perfectly, ie: http://myserver/svnrepo1 accesibly only for users on mygroup1 with theirs users of linux and passwords of svn. Also works for the other repos with their users and groups. But when i tried with websvn, shows all repos without take care than if user on mygroup1 can view repo2 (that's i dont want do). You can login as any user on mygroup1, mygroup2, or johndoe, and you login into all repositories.

I'll try to find a solution and I'll post the news, if anyone can helpme with this I'll preciated so much!!! Thanks for all

I show my files:
/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf

```
<Location /svnrepo1>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /var/myrepos/repo1
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Repositorio Subversion de MD"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
    Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /websvn/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yuo have an auth file to store the users, but no access file.
Try adding

```
AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/myrepos/conf/svnaccess.conf
```

where svnaccess has the groups specified and the user permissions.

Comment: This is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with websvn.  This is how I solved it:

First you need to have a svnaccess.conf file with the user permissions in it and it set as @gbjbaanb suggests.  Then you need to have websvn reference that file in its config.

websvn/include/config.php

```
$config->useAuthenticationFile('/var/myrepos/conf/svnauth.conf'); // Global access file
```

Answer (score 0):

AuthzSVNAccessFile should work. You can also use http method limit / apache.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484499/how-do-i-restrict-apache-svn-access-to-specific-users-ldap-file-based-authentic